# Can I view local/unix mail (`mail` in the Terminal) in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, email, cron

I use cron to run some jobs, but since that's the only thing I use my unix mail for, having this run through Mail.app would be a nicer experience than seeing "You have new mail." in the Terminal.

How can I do this?

Comment: Back in the old days when Mail.app natively used .mbox mailboxes as storage, this was as easy as setting up a symlink or two.  Nowadays Mail.app uses several SQLite databases, so even if you got it to work, I think it would be pretty fragile.  You can import mboxes still, but it's probably easier to configure a local-only dovecot IMAP/POP server, or use a more pleasant command-line mail client like mutt/alpine.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211086/use-applescript-to-send-mail-without-mail-app  for some ideas.

Comment: also see: https://gist.github.com/Moligaloo/3850710  You can run an apple script from the command line.  osascript.

Comment: This is also conceptually the same as this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231031/how-to-automatically-deliver-var-mail-user-to-my-gmail?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Brutal solution: set up postfix to handle outgoing mail, and create a ~/.forward file forwarding all mail to your "real" mail account. Not for the faint of heart but, then again, neither is running cron jobs. :)